# Firebase - Fallback to Crash Reporting

Tags: ios, firebase, crash, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

When I get into Crash Report on Firebase, I see the message:
Someone on your team has set up Crashlytics as your crash reporter for XXXXX
How can I fall back to Crash Report? I`m not ready to move on to crashlytics yet.

Answer (score 0):

Great question Rafael. If you want to switch back, simply remove the Crashlytics integration from your app and reintegrate crash reporting. Let me know how it goes and remember to talk to your team about why this happened in the first place. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with falling back to the Firebase Crash reporting after I tried setting up the Crashalytics in my app project. 
Since there were a lot of issues with the setting it up correctly  in an  existing  project and had very limited time, I had to revert the changes in my project configurations back. However, after this change  I was not able to reach the Crash reporting in the Firebase console anymore  and just  received the info :

> Someone on your team has set up Crashlytics as your crash reporter

Looks like a bug, console does not get updated after the fall back.
My personal believe is that developers are forced to move to Crashalytics...

> Note: Crashlytics will soon become the primary crash reporter for Firebase. If you aren't already using Crash Reporting to report crashes and non-fatal errors in your app, we recommend using Crashlytics.

I just gave it a last try today.
Reading carefully and slowly the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/disable-sdk) I tried this as last chance trial:

> To let you users opt-in or opt-out of using Firebase Crash Reporting, you might want to configure your app so that you can enable and disable Crash Reporting. You might also find this capability to be useful during app development and testing.

1. **Remove any added dependency  you did for Crashalitycs**  (both app and project - see [Get started with Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started) )
2. **Add back the dependency for Crash reporting:** [IOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios) or  [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android)
3. **Follow the steps:**

> **iOS:**
>   You can add a key to the Info.plist for your iOS app to disable Crash Reporting at build time.
>   Add the key **firebase_crash_collection_enabled**, and set the value to **false**.

To enable Crash Reporting call:

```
Crash.sharedInstance().crashCollectionEnabled = true
```

> **Android:**
>   You can add a meta-data entry to the AndroidManifest.xml for your app to disable Crash Reporting at build time.

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

To enable Crash Reporting call in your app onCreate() method:

```
FirebaseCrash.setCrashCollectionEnabled(true);
```

I could open Crash Reporting for the app in the console from the drop down menu on top of the console... Let me see if this will work and I will see the test crashes in the console later.